# Need bash script syntax to retrieve google drive file contents with wget

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I'd like to use wget to retrieve the contents of a google drive file using a bash script on raspbian. My efforts so far with wget download some html that opens a basic google page telling me how to use google drive for file storage. The command I'm using is:

```
wget -ncS https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nfId2iKvpaQLI5zSDQEXuTrrTt4qNz4qrHL4jFum3OM
```

The file itself is tiny for testing, just 10 characters in it.

I may be misunderstanding what wget does as I've never used it before and am not getting what I hope to get when playing with it (the file contents).

Where am I going wrong?  What is the syntax to retrieve my file?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive

Comment: Thanks.  The bit I used from that chain was https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441141/4947692

Comment: A word of advice to those using gdrive. The google APIs they are built on have limits. How some of the gdrive options deliver functionality may use more than one API feature, thus consuming more quote units.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Aulis for directing me to the answer.
I used gdrive as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441141/4947692

Comment: You're welcome. Great work!